# Há como impedir o uso de "new" em uma função do JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, funções, construtor

Supondo a função:

```
function foo() {
  return 'something';
}
```

É possível invocá-la (operação abstrata `[[Call]]`):

```
// Invocando `foo`:
foo();
```

<sup>No exemplo acima, seria retornado a string `something.`</sup>

Mas também é possível utilizá-la como construtor (operação abstrata `[[Construct]]`):

```
// Construindo um novo objeto `foo`:
new foo();
```

<sup>No exemplo acima, como `foo` não foi criada com o objetivo de *atuar* como construtora, um objeto "vazio" (do "tipo" `foo`) é retornado.</sup>

---

Há casos como esse no qual uma função não deve ser utilizada como construtora, portanto, pergunto-me se é possível impedir o uso de `new`.

Sei que em alguns casos pode ser útil (principalmente quando `class` não existia), mas gostaria de saber se tem como "bloquear" (i.e. lançar algum erro) ao tentar utilizar `new` em `foo`? Ou seja, só quero que a invocação seja permitida.

É possível?

Comment: do ponto de vista de prototipagem do javascript é até interessante mas... em qual caso real alguém ia quer precisar disso? confesso que nunca vi ninguém tentar usar uma *function* (que existe só como "método") como uma instancia, e já vi muito código na minha vida :)

Comment: Também mantenho o seu questionamento, @RicardoPontual, de fato é um _caso de uso_ pouco comum. De todo modo, não acho que cabe pensar "onde poderia ser utilizado" (até porque é impossível listar esse tipo de possibilidade), mas sim _mostrar_ a possibilidade.

Comment: eu entendo, só queria saber se existe algum caso de uso pra isso, mas como disse, como conhecimento é interessante, mas seria mais se tivesse algum exemplo prático :)

Comment: @RicardoPontual, existe algum uso. Veja o exemplo desse [post no SOEn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9584719/date-vs-new-date-in-javascript). Trata sobre a diferença em usar `let d = new Date();` e `let d = Date();` no primeiro caso é retornado um objeto `Date` e no segundo caso é retornada uma `String` com a data atual.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Uma alternativa é verificar o `this`. Você pode fazer um `if` para verificar se o `this` é uma instância da própria função.

Algo como:

```js
function foo() {
  if (this instanceof foo) {
    throw new Error('Cannot be used as a constructor.');
  }

  return 'something';
}

console.log(foo()); // "something"
console.log(new foo()); // Error: Cannot be used as a constructor.
```

Eu vi um exemplo parecido como esse em um código de programação funcional em JavaScript, no qual a função só podia ser invocada, jamais instanciada.

Answer (score 6):

Uma alternativa é utilizar a construção sintática `new.target`, que refere-se à função construtora quando a função é chamada utilizando o operador `new`.

Assim, se `new.target` estiver definido, infere-se que a função foi chamada através de instanciação com `new` – caso este que queremos proibir:

```js
function foo() {
  if (new.target) {
    throw new Error('Cannot be used as a constructor.');
  }

  return 'something';
}

console.log(foo()); //=> "something"
console.log(new foo()); // Error: Cannot be used as constructor.
```

---

### Sobre `new.target`

A construção sintática [`new.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new.target) inclui uma referência à função construtora quando esta é instanciada utilizando o operador `new`.

<sup>Em termos sintáticos, `target` parece ser uma propriedade de um *suposto objeto* `new`. No entanto, como `new` é um operador (e não um objeto), diz-se que `new.target` é uma construção sintática ou *pseudo-propriedade*.</sup>

De acordo com a documentação, quando uma função é instanciada utilizando o operador `new` (operação abstrata `[[Construct]]`), a *pseudo-propriedade* `new.target` referir-se-á à função construtora. Por outro lado, quando a função for chamada normalmente (operação abstrata `[[Call]]`), `new.target` será `undefined`.

Exemplos:

```js
function foo(msg) {
  console.log(msg + ':', new.target);
}

class Bar {
  constructor(msg) {
    console.log(msg + ':', new.target);
  }
}

foo('Sem new'); //=> undefined
new foo('Com new'); //=> Refere-se à função `foo` (construtor)
new Bar('Classe com new'); //=> Refere-se à classe `Bar` (construtor)
```

Para mais detalhes sobre `new.target`, referir à [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new.target).